# Server side validation if Javascript disabled on user's browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, form, validation

I have developed a small form with 3 input type = text and one input type = submit button. The end user fills the form and submit it, but no data inserted into backend List. (probably empty form is submitted). I get to know that Javascript is disabled on user's browser. Now i want to do server side validation. How i validate my form on server side? I need a piece of code to validate form on server side (code behinde) ? I need code in asp.net

Comment: How is this related to SharePoint? Are you referring to a List form or Application page, Web part??

Comment: yes, i am using SP list for storing data and i am working on application page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button click method try calling

```
Page.Validate()

//OR

Page.Validate("[Name of validation group]")
```

and then:

```
if(Page.IsValid) {
    //Go ahead and submit your data to SharePoint.
}
```